# Group properties with Less CSS

Tags: css, less

I've created a mixin which auto-generates whatever classes you throw at it. My goal is to be able to combine properties. For instance, you might want this:

```
.py-20 {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

But the mixin does this:

```
.py-20 {
    padding-top: 20rem;
}
.py-20 {
    padding-bottom: 20rem;
}
```

Here's the complete Less code

```
@padding: {
    20:             2rem;
    30:             3rem;
}

@responsive-modifiers: true;

#config () {
    .generate(py, padding-top, @padding);
    .generate(py, padding-bottom, @padding);
}

#config();

.generate(@prefix, @property, @list) {
    each(@list, {
        .@{prefix}-@{key} {
            @{property}: @value;
        }
    });
}
```

Ideas would be welcome!

Comment: Just to clarify, your problem is that youre getting 2 rules instead of a combined rule?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I’d like both possibilities; single and/or combined rules

Comment: You can achive this compression after generating css code from less. Some css minifiers can combine rules. For example https://csscompressor.com/ Try to look for plugin for your build system.

Comment: Sure, I could achieve this with Gulp. But I'd like to manage it without a build tool!

Comment: You'll have to restructure things so that your `each` is inside the class declaration - `.something { each(…)}`. But what's the context that makes single vs combined matter?